# Setting spacing per breakpoint in Bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap-5

I thought it was possible to set spacing (margin/padding) per breakpoint in Bootstrap 5?

Something like `mb-sm-2` doesn't seem to work... Should it...?

I have checked [the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/) but don't really understand what it's saying - it sounds like breakpoints are supported... ‍♂️

[image: Bootstrap 5 spacing notations]

Comment: if, Here, You want to set only small device breakpoints. So, You need to use this `<div class="mb-sm-2 mb-md-0">My Text</div>`.

Comment: Oooh, so you can only use an sm breakpoint if you specify md (or others) in addition...?

Comment: when you does call only `sm` so, It will call small device and upper breakpoints. So, if, You want to call only one breakpoints. So, You will need to add upper breakpoints for stop as according to it. Hope, You are understand.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Break points are supported in Bootstrap 5.
From the docs if you want to set margin or padding for extra small dimensions(<576px) .You use

```
<div class="mb-2"></div>
```

That though will affect all dimensions as it is not under any specified media query.
If you want to specify margin on small dimensions(≥576px) . You use

```
<div class="mb-sm-2"></div>
```

That will affect dimensions that are equal and greater than 576px. In case you want that to take place only on small dimensions. You use

```
<div class="mb-sm-2 mb-md-0"></div>
```

Dimensions that are equal to and greater than 768px  and those less 576px will not have the specified margin.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 5 uses for breakpoints a different syntax comparing with previous versions.
The available breakpoints are as follows

```
| Breakpoint        | Class infix | Dimensions |
|-------------------|-------------|------------|
| X-Small           | None        | <576px  |
| Small             | sm          | ≥576px     |
| Medium            | md          | ≥768px     |
| Large             | lg          | ≥992px     |
| Extra large       | xl          | ≥1200px    |
| Extra extra large | xxl         | ≥1400px    |
```

Here is a particular example: in order to get 0 margin and 0 padding ONLY for screens with lower resolution as X-Small(<576px) use something like this:

```
class="m-0 p-0 m-sm-4 p-sm-4"
```

where m-0 and p-0 will be applied only for resolution <576px  and m-sm-4 and p-sm-4 for ≥576px resolution.